# SQL Server and Oracle terminology

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

SQL Server and Oracle terminology -

[image]

[image]

In SQL Server If I have two applications and want to keep the database completely separate, I could simply create 1 database for each application therefore I end up with 2 databases.

If I wanted to do the same thing in oracle, what do I need to create? 
- create a new "Databases"? "Instance", "Schema", or "Tablespace" per application?
(Note, these two applications is the same application used by two different companies, that do not share data!)

Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492342/Concept-mapping-between-SQL-Server-and-Oracle

Comment: In oracle you can create two schemas in the same database, one for each application.

Answer (score 4):

Having worked with SQL Server a lot in the past, I have sympathy with trying to figure out how Oracle organizes things as I struggled with the same thing. My comments below are from SQL Server 2000 and 2003 so forgive me if things have changed since then.

Previous responders have been helpful. I think one problematic assumption here is that there is an exact "level" equivalency between SQL Server and Oracle. What I mean by "level" is something that occupies the same space in the hierarchies that you have diagrammed above (and which, btw, I think are a good place to start but might need a bit of editing in a couple of places, for example how you have diagrammed "user" and "schema" in the Oracle hierarchy, I might put them side-by-side.) I do not think these concept "levels" match exactly between the DB platforms.

A schema in Oracle is somewhat equivalent to a separate database in SQL Server but not entirely.

I would say that the "walls" -- not an exact technical term but oh well -- between databases in SQL server are a bit higher than the "walls" between schemas in Oracle. Others might disagree but here is my reasoning:

a. A schema in Oracle is a purely logical construct. It denotes who has **ownership** of objects. It has nothing to do with the physical location or layout of the objects. A tablespace (orthagonal concept, as noted by a previous poster) indicates the **physical** location of objects. A tablespace can hold objects that are in multiple schemas and vice versa. In SQL Server these two concepts are sort of merged into one -- a database is both tablespace and schema, more or less, although in some respects within a DB in SQL Server you then have multiple owners with various object ownership. This can get a bit confusing because as I remember (it's been a couple of years) if not using NT Authentication the users are defined at the server level and then have to "link" to the users in the individual DBs.

b. I remember finding it easier, or at least a bit simpler, to assure myself that users to two separate DBs in SQL Server had no access to the relative other user's DB than I have found it in Oracle.

c. Because a DB in SQL server represents both physical storage and logical ownership, you can detach the DB and move it to another SQL Server Instance and attach it. You can't do this with a schema in Oracle. I mean, you can datapump the data out or back it up or whatever to another server and another schema, but that all takes at least some scripting and such or at least a fair amount of clicking in Enterprise Manager. It doesn't give you the one-click "Detach DB" option that you have in SQL Server which makes it a lot easier to get the idea that SQL Server DBs are units that you can more-or-less move back and forth between databases.

To sum things up, I think either option would work. That is, 1) Create two separate instances of Oracle with one schema in each instance for each application, or 2) Create two separate schemas in one Oracle instance.

There are pros and cons for each option. Option 1 is probably going to be more work to set up and configure but will also give you more separation, independence, ability to have separate hardware, etc., for each DB. Option 2 will be quite a bit simpler but gives you less separation between the data and greater risk of configuration screw-ups or other things allowing users of one schema to access the other. It also means you have to be a bit more careful that someone writing a query accessing data in one schema doesn't use all the CPU and IO resources and starve a user on the other schema.

Also, yes, you could use pluggable databases in 12c. However, given the fact that you need to ask these questions (no shame, just pointing out where you're at) makes me hesitant about recommending what can easily be a more complex setup.

TL;DR -- SQL Server isn't Oracle and Oracle isn't SQL Server. Either option works and there are pros and cons to each.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using 12.1 or later with the multitenant option, you could create separate pluggable databases in a single container database.  The other option, which works in any version of Oracle, would be to create a separate schema.  It would be possible, as well, to create a separate database, though that is generally not the preferred approach unless you have a particular need to do things like upgrade the database that one application is using without affecting the other.

**Creating a Database**

If you create a separate database, you'd end up with complete separate memory structures (i.e. the SGA and PGA for each database would be separate) as well as a completely separate set of background processes (each database would have its own log writer process(es) for example).  That is a very heavyweight option-- you can't have too many databases on a single server before you start having a lot of contention for RAM, for scheduling all the background processes, etc.  It does provide for the maximum separation between different applications-- each database can be running a different version of Oracle with a different set of initialization parameters-- but this also tends to increase the complexity of managing the environment.  This generally only makes sense when you have third party applications that require a specific version of the database or a specific set of initialization parameters.

**Creating a Schema**

If you create a separate schema, you still have a single database so the two schemas are sharing the same memory structures (competing with each other for space in the SGA's buffer cache, for example), initialization parameters, etc.  You have to exercise a modicum of planning to ensure that that the two don't interfere with each other-- you'd probably want to make sure that nether application creates public synonyms or at least that they won't wan to create the same public synonym as the other application-- but this is generally pretty trivial.

**Creating a Pluggable Database**

This only works in 12.1 and only if you have the multitenant option.  This is the most similar to the SQL Server concept of creating a new database for each application.

Comment: do schema contain tablespaces? what exactly are a tablespaces?

Comment: @001 - Schemas and tablespaces are orthogonal concepts.  A tablespace is a collection of data files.  You could, as a matter of convention, create separate tablespaces for each application.  Or you could use a single tablespace (or set of tablespaces) for all applications.  Separate tablespaces might be beneficial if you wanted to be able to restore one application to a point in time without affecting another or to allow the database to continue running if on tablespace's data files were lost/ corrupted and needed to be recovered.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a new instance (schema) on the same database, where the schema in oracle is the same as the SQL server database

Comment: A "schema" and an "instance" are very different things so "a new instance (schema)" is not correct.  Creating a new schema makes sense.  Creating a new database makes sense.  Creating a new instance would mean adding a node to a RAC cluster (or turning a non-RAC database into a two-node RAC database) and would have nothing to do with adding a new application.